# How to calculate weights for RNN?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm trying to implement a Recurrent Neural Network to get a better understanding of what is doing.

I have taken [some code](http://iamtrask.github.io/2015/07/12/basic-python-network/%20code) from a FFNN, in order to extend it to a RNN.

Following this equation:

[image: equation for RNN]

I have made some progress, but I'm stuck when I need to update the weights. I don't know how to do the calculation.

```
import numpy as np

def nonlin(x,deriv=False):
    if(deriv==True):
        return x*(1-x)

    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))


'''
Add two binary numbers

Each column is a time step.

00110100

01001101

10000001
'''

X = np.array([[0,1],
             [0,0],
             [1,1],
             [0,1],
             [1,0],
             [1,0],
             [0,1],
             [0,0]])

Y = np.array([[1],
              [0],
              [0],
              [0],
              [0],
              [0],
              [0],
              [1]])

np.random.seed(1)

# randomly initialize our weights with mean 0
syn0 = 2*np.random.random((1,2)) - 1
syn1 = 2*np.random.random((1,1)) - 1
l1_t = 2*np.random.random((1,1)) - 1 # past example
syn2 = 2*np.random.random((1,1)) - 1

for x, y in zip(X, Y):

    # Feed forward through layers 0, 1, and 2
    l0 = x.reshape(2, 1)
    l1 = nonlin(np.add(np.dot(syn0, l0), np.dot(syn1, l1_t)))
    l2 = nonlin(np.dot(syn2, l1))

    # how much did we miss the target value?
    l2_error = y - l2

    print "Error:" + str(np.mean(np.abs(l2_error)))

    # in what direction is the target value?
    # were we really sure? if so, don't change too much.
    l2_delta = l2_error*nonlin(l2,deriv=True)

    # how much did each l1 value contribute to the l2 error (according to the weights)?
    l1_t_error = l2_delta.dot(syn1.T)
    l1_t_delta = l1_t_error *nonlin(l1,deriv=True)
    l1_error = l2_delta.dot(syn0)

    # in what direction is the target l1?
    # were we really sure? if so, don't change too much.
    l1_delta = l1_error * nonlin(l1,deriv=True)

    syn2 += l2.T.dot(l2_delta)
    syn1 += l1.T.dot(l1_t_delta)
    syn0 += l0.T.dot(l1_delta)

    # Save l1 for next iteration
    l1_t = l1
```

I also tried to search for clues, but so far the tutorials are very academic and I get lost in the notation of the derivatives.

Comment: Can you clarify what you need here? Code review is off topic here. Are you just wondering how to convert the formulas at the top into Python code?

Comment: He's asking how to perform the weight update for W_hh, W_ho, and W_ih. I believe that much is clear from the title and the last sentence before his code.

Comment: I agree with Axoren. I said it in the title and repeated it in the sentence before the code. I didn't know putting the code would bring such confusion. Next time I will give less information, so as to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use a full "basic" example:

https://github.com/gwtaylor/theano-rnn/blob/master/rnn.py

You can look at the Theano docs to see what math has been abstracted away.

Basic strategy of what you're looking for is here I think...

## compute the gradient of cost with respect to theta = (W, W_in, W_out)

```
    # gradients on the weights using BPTT
    gparams = []
    for param in self.rnn.params:
        gparam = T.grad(cost, param)
        gparams.append(gparam)

    updates = {}
    for param, gparam in zip(self.rnn.params, gparams):
        weight_update = self.rnn.updates[param]
        upd = mom * weight_update - l_r * gparam
        updates[weight_update] = upd
        updates[param] = param + upd
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer. I still find the code alone not to be clear enough. I think it would be more useful to have a commented code stating what it is doing every step of the way (and how it relates to the math). That code tries to reuse structures of Theano (which is what you would expect in a library). I think would be more useful to have code that it is entirely written for teaching/example purposes.